# dropped packets on the interface

Tags: linux, centos, debian

i am running centos 6.2 and one of the interfaces has high dropped packets.
this is the info from ethtool, is this is a network issue??

```
[root@w native]# ifconfig eth1
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:1F:74:2E:6A:80
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:38459399 errors:0 dropped:38459399 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2334427918 (2.1 GiB)  TX bytes:258 (258.0 b)

[root@wye native]# ethtool eth1
Settings for eth1:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   1000baseT/Full
                                10000baseT/Full
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full
                                10000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: Unknown
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: d
        Link detected: yes


[root@w native]# ethtool -k eth1
Offload parameters for eth1:
rx-checksumming: on
tx-checksumming: on
scatter-gather: on
tcp-segmentation-offload: on
udp-fragmentation-offload: off
generic-segmentation-offload: on
generic-receive-offload: on
large-receive-offload: off

[root@w native]# ethtool -S eth1
NIC statistics:
     tx_events: 12086471
     rx_crc_errors: 0
     rx_alignment_symbol_errors: 0
     rx_pause_frames: 0
     rx_control_frames: 0
     rx_in_range_errors: 0
     rx_out_range_errors: 0
     rx_frame_too_long: 0
     rx_address_match_errors: 163123495
     rx_dropped_too_small: 0
     rx_dropped_too_short: 0
     rx_dropped_header_too_small: 0
     rx_dropped_tcp_length: 0
     rx_dropped_runt: 0
     rxpp_fifo_overflow_drop: 0
     rx_input_fifo_overflow_drop: 0
     rx_ip_checksum_errs: 0
     rx_tcp_checksum_errs: 4
     rx_udp_checksum_errs: 2
     tx_pauseframes: 0
     tx_controlframes: 0
     rx_priority_pause_frames: 0
     pmem_fifo_overflow_drop: 0
     jabber_events: 0
     rx_drops_no_pbuf: 0
     rx_drops_no_txpb: 0
     rx_drops_no_erx_descr: 0
     rx_drops_no_tpre_descr: 0
     rx_drops_too_many_frags: 0
     rx_drops_invalid_ring: 0
     forwarded_packets: 35
     rx_drops_mtu: 0
     eth_red_drops: 0
     be_on_die_temperature: 50
     rxq0: rx_bytes: 2299912112
     rxq0: rx_pkts: 38331860
     rxq0: rx_polls: 37803085
     rxq0: rx_events: 0
     rxq0: rx_compl: 38331860
     rxq0: rx_mcast_pkts: 14
     rxq0: rx_post_fail: 0
     rxq0: rx_drops_no_skbs: 0
     rxq0: rx_drops_no_frags: 0
     rxq1: rx_bytes: 3398729
     rxq1: rx_pkts: 16154
     rxq1: rx_polls: 9846
     rxq1: rx_events: 0
     rxq1: rx_compl: 16154
     rxq1: rx_mcast_pkts: 3392
     rxq1: rx_post_fail: 0
     rxq1: rx_drops_no_skbs: 0
     rxq1: rx_drops_no_frags: 0
     rxq2: rx_bytes: 206100
     rxq2: rx_pkts: 3379
     rxq2: rx_polls: 3379
     rxq2: rx_events: 0
     rxq2: rx_compl: 3379
     rxq2: rx_mcast_pkts: 3319
     rxq2: rx_post_fail: 0
     rxq2: rx_drops_no_skbs: 0
     rxq2: rx_drops_no_frags: 0
     rxq3: rx_bytes: 30735472
     rxq3: rx_pkts: 105087
     rxq3: rx_polls: 105087
     rxq3: rx_events: 0
     rxq3: rx_compl: 105087
     rxq3: rx_mcast_pkts: 11078
     rxq3: rx_post_fail: 0
     rxq3: rx_drops_no_skbs: 0
     rxq3: rx_drops_no_frags: 0
     rxq4: rx_bytes: 180245
     rxq4: rx_pkts: 2998
     rxq4: rx_polls: 2998
     rxq4: rx_events: 0
     rxq4: rx_compl: 2998
     rxq4: rx_mcast_pkts: 2984
     rxq4: rx_post_fail: 0
     rxq4: rx_drops_no_skbs: 0
     rxq4: rx_drops_no_frags: 0
     txq0: tx_compl: 0
     txq0: tx_bytes: 0
     txq0: tx_pkts: 0
     txq0: tx_reqs: 0
     txq0: tx_wrbs: 0
     txq0: tx_compl: 0
     txq0: tx_stops: 0
     txq1: tx_compl: 0
     txq1: tx_bytes: 0
     txq1: tx_pkts: 0
     txq1: tx_reqs: 0
     txq1: tx_wrbs: 0
     txq1: tx_compl: 0
     txq1: tx_stops: 0
     txq2: tx_compl: 0
     txq2: tx_bytes: 0
     txq2: tx_pkts: 0
     txq2: tx_reqs: 0
     txq2: tx_wrbs: 0
     txq2: tx_compl: 0
     txq2: tx_stops: 0
     txq3: tx_compl: 0
     txq3: tx_bytes: 0
     txq3: tx_pkts: 0
     txq3: tx_reqs: 0
     txq3: tx_wrbs: 0
     txq3: tx_compl: 0
     txq3: tx_stops: 0
     txq4: tx_compl: 3
     txq4: tx_bytes: 258
     txq4: tx_pkts: 3
     txq4: tx_reqs: 3
     txq4: tx_wrbs: 6
     txq4: tx_compl: 3
     txq4: tx_stops: 0
     txq5: tx_compl: 0
     txq5: tx_bytes: 0
     txq5: tx_pkts: 0
     txq5: tx_reqs: 0
     txq5: tx_wrbs: 0
     txq5: tx_compl: 0
     txq5: tx_stops: 0
     txq6: tx_compl: 0
     txq6: tx_bytes: 0
     txq6: tx_pkts: 0
     txq6: tx_reqs: 0
     txq6: tx_wrbs: 0
     txq6: tx_compl: 0
     txq6: tx_stops: 0
     txq7: tx_compl: 0
     txq7: tx_bytes: 0
     txq7: tx_pkts: 0
     txq7: tx_reqs: 0
     txq7: tx_wrbs: 0
     txq7: tx_compl: 0
     txq7: tx_stops: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide any information on what the server or application is doing? Assuming you have a managed switch, are there any corresponding errors on the switch port?

- In general, check the physical bits first (cabling).
- Check the interface statistics on the related switch ports (you tagged this `debian`, so are you sending data between two systems?)
- Examine your system load and processor utilization on the system with the interface errors.
- Run tests. If you're communication between two servers, [iperf](http://iperf.sourceforge.net/) is a good network load generator for this type of testing.
- If this is consistent or repeatable, you could analyze a `tcpdump` of the relevant interface.
- *optional* - Explore sysctl.conf settings... This is really based on what your server is doing. If this were a messaging application or something that requires heavy throughout, we could look at network buffer settings, etc. I've been playing with the [dropwatch](https://fedorahosted.org/dropwatch/) utility [described here](http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2011/07/11/using-netstat-and-dropwatch-to-observe-packet-loss-on-linux-servers/) as well.

Comment: I don't think this is a physical issue - the kernel is receiving all of these packets w/o errors.  The ifconfig indicates that it's part of a bonded link - the bonding configuration on both the host and the upstream switch... It may be receiving frames in the context of the channel that aren't supposed to be delivered.

Comment: I didn't notice the `SLAVE` in the ifconfig output. Good catch. There are still missing details, so this is enough to start exploring.